# How does XCode memory leak detection work?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

How does the XCode Instrument Leak tool figure out if an object is a leak or just something not released yet? 
I'm pretty new to Objective C, the leak tool detects a leak in the code I work with. But the code looks sound to me. So just wondering how much can I trust this tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "leak" as an object that's still allocated, but your application no longer has a reference
pointing to that object. Since you no longer have a reference, there's no way you will be able to release the object, thus it's a leak.

As the [leaks(1) man page](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/leaks.1.html) says:

> leaks identifies leaked memory -- memory that the application has allocated, but has been lost and cannot be freed.  Specifically, leaks examines a specified process's memory for values that may be pointers to malloc-allocated buffers.  Any buffer reachable from a pointer in writable memory, a register,
>        or on the stack is assumed to be memory in use.  Any buffer reachable from a pointer in a reachable
>        malloc-allocated buffer is also assumed to be in use.  The buffers which are not reachable are leaks;
>        the buffers could never be freed because no pointer exists in memory to the buffer, and thus free()
>        could never be called for these buffers

You might also want to look into the ObjectAlloc tool in Instruments.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what leak is, just wondering if XCode has a reputation of giving false alarms. Thanks for pointing out ObjectAlloc tool, I found what the problem is with its help. There is indeed a leak.

Comment: The leaks tool has gotten much much better over time.  It rarely spits out a false positive these days. Very rarely.